# Show content based on radio option click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, logic

I have 2 radio buttons.

I would like to show the div when the radio is selected.
As default, the default must be selected and the content is shown.

```
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="m-radio-inline mt-3">
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="1"  checked> First
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="2" required=""> Second
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first">First Content</div>
<div class="second">Second Content</div>
```

What is the best way of doing this with Javascript?
My code
https://jsfiddle.net/cbkm9vxg/

Comment: Use the change event and show/hide your content? What have you tried so far?

Comment: document.getElementById('first').style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById('second').style.visibility = 'hidden';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `.hidden` class to hide an element, assign it by default and then add/remove is as needed when the radio elements are clicked.

```js
// radio element click event handler
var radioClickHandler = function() {
  var first = document.querySelector('.first');
  var second = document.querySelector('.second');

  // show/hide required elements depending on which radio element was clicked.
  if (this.value == 1) {
    first.classList.remove('hidden');
    second.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    first.classList.add('hidden');
    second.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

// Get All Radio Elements
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]');

// Apply click event
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('click', radioClickHandler);
}

// Apply Default
radioClickHandler.apply(radios[0]);
```

```css
/*hides element*/
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="m-radio-inline mt-3">
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="1"  checked> First
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="2" required=""> Second
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first">First Content</div>
<div class="second">Second Content</div>
```

Comment: my only problem is snce I have other radio button in my page, other radio button's first and last also effects the content. How can I fix this issue

Comment: There si many ways to solve that, you could give the buttons you want to attach the events to specific attributes, such as `data-id="xxx"` then use `document.querySelector('[data-id="xxx"]')` to bind to them.

Comment: if you could add your preffered method to the code snippet I would appricate that. Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing, I have no idea what the rest of your page looks like. If you have multiple groups of radio buttons and only want to apply the logic to a specific subset you need to add those specific scenarios to a new question as it is different to the current question and none of the current solution would apply.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a `change` event listener on your radioboxes.

For an easier use, add a common class to your text divs *(here, `text-div`)*.

Inside the event handler, check if the input was checked with `this.checked`, hide all `.text-div` divs and only show the one with the index similar to the radiobox value *(-1, because it's a 0-indexed array)* :

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".m-radio input");

let myFunction = function() {
  if(this.checked){
    //Get all your text divs
    let els = document.querySelectorAll('.text-div');
    for(let el of els){
      //Hide them all
      el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    //Only show the one with the same index as the radiobox value - 1
    els[(+this.value) - 1].style.display = 'block';
    
  }
};

//Attach your event handler for every radiobox
for (let element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener('change', myFunction, false);
}

//Show the first text div at the start
document.querySelectorAll('.text-div')[0].style.display = 'block';
```

```css
.text-div{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="m-radio-inline mt-3">
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="1"  checked> First
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="2" required=""> Second
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-div first">First Content</div>
<div class="text-div second">Second Content</div>
```

Comment: the "Second Content" class has same name as first content. The first time I posted I mistyped and update. It will be <div class="second">Second Content</div>
Would it change your code? Because now you have for etc.

Comment: @SNaRe You'll have to give a common class to all your divs, and use this class in the `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
document.getElementById('firstDiv').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('secondDiv').style.display = 'none';

function onChangeRadio() {

  var x = document.getElementById('first').checked;

  if (x) {
    document.getElementById('firstDiv').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('secondDiv').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('firstDiv').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('secondDiv').style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="m-radio-inline mt-3">
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input onclick="onChangeRadio()" id="first" type="radio" name="type" value="1"  checked> First
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input onclick="onChangeRadio()" id="second" type="radio" name="type" value="2" required=""> Second
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="firstDiv" class="first">First Content</div>
<div id="secondDiv" class="second">Second Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly Simple so i'll go with a simple answer.

If you couldn't figure this on your own, then this should be as simple for you to try and understand.

```js
function onClick(e){
 if (e.target.value == 1) 
 {
  document.querySelector('.first').style.display='block';
  document.querySelector('.second').style.display='none';
 }
 else if (e.target.value == 2)
 {
  document.querySelector('.first').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('.second').style.display='block';
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="m-radio-inline mt-3">
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" onclick="onClick(event);" name="type" value="1"  checked> First
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" onclick="onClick(event);" name="type" value="2" required=""> Second
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div  class="first">First Content</div>
<div style="display:none;" class="second">Second Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  document.querySelector('.second').style.display = 'none';

  document.querySelector('.m-radio-inline').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let traget = event.target.querySelector('input');
    let targetValue = traget && traget.value;
    if (targetValue) {
      document.querySelector(`.${targetValue}`).style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector(`.${targetValue == 'second'?'first': 'second'}`).style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not changing your original html.

```html
<div class="m-form__group form-group row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="m-radio-inline mt-3">
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="1"  checked> First
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label class="m-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="2" required=""> Second
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="first">First Content</div>
<div class="second">Second Content</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

  var _tinputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i = 0; i < _tinputs.length; i++) {
    _tinputs[i].onclick = function(evt) {
      var _firstdiv = document.querySelectorAll('.first')[0];
      var _secdiv = document.querySelectorAll('.second')[0];

      var _clicked_val = this.value;

      if (_clicked_val === '1') {
        _firstdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        _secdiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
      if (_clicked_val === '2') {
        _secdiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        _firstdiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    };
  }

  //set default
  document.querySelectorAll('.second')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple code below first initialise the required html dom elements, then bind the event.

```
var firstContent, secondContent;

   function initialize() {
    firstContent = $('.first');
    secondContent = $('.second');
   }

   function bindEvents() {
    $('[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    render();
    });
   }

   function render() {
    if(1 == $('[type="radio"]:checked').val()) {
    firstContent.show();
    secondContent.hide();
    } else {
    firstContent.hide();
    secondContent.show();
    }
   }

   initialize();
   bindEvents();
   render();
```

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hxqkauLd/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```html
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#div1{background:red;}
#div2{background:blue;}
.hidden{display:none;}
</style>

</head>

<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio1">red
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio1">blue

<div id="div1">Red</div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden">Blue</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#radio1').click(function(){
 $('div').hide();
 $('#div1').show();
});
$('#radio2').click(function(){
 $('div').hide();
 $('#div2').show();
});
});

</script> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP never said anything about jQuery.

Comment: Yet not what OP was asking.